# Audio word API similar to dictionary.com

Tags: api

I was looking into dictionary.com word pronunciation API.They require an extra fee to use their api.

Was wondering if someone knew of some similar API's that are free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wordnik Developer](http://developer.wordnik.com)